# Check whether attribute is equal to value, different from value, or undefined

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the below xsl:choose tag based on certain conditions

```
<MaturityDate>
 <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="../../../../@name !='WQA'">
        <xsl:value-of select="Apsml:unadjustedDate"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="Apsml:adjustedTerminationDate"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</MaturityDate>
```

Now as shown above, if the name is equal to WQA then do something or if the product is not WQA then it do something. Now I want to add a third condition which is if the both the above conditions are not true then it should display null

```
<xsl:value-of select="'null'" />
```

please advise how to add the third condition that if the both the conditions are not true then it should display as null at last

Answer (score 2):

The value of attribute `name` can either be equal to `'WQA'` or different from `'WQA'`; the (only) other alternative is that the attribute does not exist.

So, you can use:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="../../../../@name ='WQA'">
        <xsl:value-of select="Apsml:adjustedTerminationDate" /> 
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="../../../../@name !='WQA'">
        <xsl:value-of select="Apsml:unadjustedDate" /> 
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- @name does not exist -->
        <xsl:value-of select="'null'" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

If you want to explicitly check for the case when the attribute does not exist, you can use the test `not(../../../../@name)`.